# Script to remove the c comments in a json file

Tags: python, json, bash

Suppose there is json file but some c style comments /* ... */ have been added to increase the readability like

```
{
 "filename" : "alice " , /* name of the file */
 /**
   assume this case never happens "filename" : "alice /*bob*/"
 **/

  /***
    some comments
  */
  "files" : "/scratch/*"  /* it should not remove "/scratch/*" */
}
```

How to write a script preferably bash or python that removes the comments from the json and return the correct json like

```
{
   "filename":"alice ",
   "files" :  "/scratch/*"
}
```

Comment: You could use regular expressions.

Comment: @rosh: No, he needs to use a parser.

Comment: Apparently it's not clear to everyone, so could you update your question to say what should happen to `{"foo": "This is a /* test */"}`? Should it remove that, or leave it alone as it's inside a string?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder AFAIK c-style comments are NOT part of json spec. A parser won't be able to handle it. Unless you propose to extend the syntax of json and write a new parser...

Comment: @Shai: Obviously. I didn't mean an off-the-shelf parser. I meant a customized one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in that case I would vote to close as "too broad" :(

Comment: If you're flexible with what format to use, go with yaml. It supports comments, so you don't have to hack together a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the [advice](https://plus.google.com/+DouglasCrockfordEsq/posts/RK8qyGVaGSr) from [Douglas Crockford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford) is appropriate here:

> Suppose you are using JSON to keep configuration files, which you would like to annotate. Go ahead and insert all the comments you like. Then pipe it through [JSMin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) before handing it to your JSON parser.

Comment: I should have thought of that... Excellent suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Since JSON doesn't have C-style comments, you'll need to customize a JSON parser to handle them in the pseudo-JSON text. Crockford has two JSON parsers written in JavaScript [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) and the http://json.org site has a list of JSON parsers in just about any language you could want. You'll need to take one and modify it to handle the comments.

Comment: for this case can't we write a simple script?

Comment: @AnkitVallecha: It won't be *simple*, but it may not be that bad. You'd have to keep track of whether you're in a string (being sure to handle escaped quotes within strings), track whether you're in a comment, etc. It might be just as simple to modify an existing JSON parser, and it would probably be more robust to modify a proper parser. (Edge cases always crop up.) But sure, you *may* be able to write a relatively short program to do it.